# In Ember-1.0.0-pre4, what is the right way to hide a rendered template?

Tags: ember.js

In previous versions of Ember I would do the following:

```
someRoute: Ember.Route.extend({
  showDialog: function (router) {
    router.get("applicationController").connectOutlet("dialog", "dialog");
  },
  hideDialog: function (router) {
    router.get("applicationController").disconnectOutlet("dialog");
  }
});
```

What is the right way to do the same in the current version of Ember?

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1867

Answer (score 0):

You still have a `connectOutlet`-esque approach in the current version of Ember. I suppose you need to question whether this is the **best** approach, but is possible.

For example:

```
someRoute: Ember.Route.extend({
    showDialog: function (router) {
        this.controllerFor('application').set('dialog', this.controllerFor('dialog'));
    },
    hideDialog: function (router) {
        this.controllerFor('application').set('dialog', null);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why is that? Surely with an if statement in Handlebars around dialog, you should be able to achieve something similar: `{{#if controller.dialog}}`

Comment: Now I see what you suggest. Sure it will work. Though I hope there is (or will be soon) a more Ember-spirited solution.